# Bow hold and broken thumb? Suggestions?

Tags: learning, strings, violin, bow, viola

So it feels like I'm fighting the bow due to the angle of my thumb, it's not impossible but I could use a few pointers or suggestions. The standard bow hold is mildly ineffective for me.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I would like to point out 2 very inspiring people to me.**

First is **Adrian Anantawan**:

Second is **Casey Driessen**:

The first case is the one of a least said fantastic violinist that does not have one hand.
The second case is a of a bluegrass legend (despite still being quite young) that holds the bow in what a classical educated person would say the wrong way (on the youtube link I posted there are sometimes 2 cameras and this makes it possible to see that).

**What is the point with these references? to say: we are all different, and everyone has to find its own way.**

Having that said, what you need to find is comfort. Find a position that is comfortable and does not hurt.

I normally say to my students to grab a glass of water in the air. When they make that position with the hand (in the air) I put the bow between the hand and they find the rest from there. This is a pointer as you asked.

Another pointer is to try Casey's thumb approach. Notice that he holds the bow with the thumb on the [**frog**](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Violin_bow_parts.jpg). He is a professional world class player and that is the way that works best for him.

Last pointer is for you to try holding the bow (and exercise this sometimes) with just 3 [**fingers**](http://www.simplybodylanguage.com/images/finger-names.jpg). The thumb, the index finger and the pinky. This will create a stress moment maybe. If you find a position where you can control the bow enough to draw a circle in the air with the point of the bow (and without pressing/forcing the hand), then that position might be the one.

Comment: Thanks once again Sergio, you seem to be the one with the answers to my questions the last week. I've actually gone and attached a significant amount of rubber bands to the frog in various gripping points that's helped greatly.

Comment: @CynthiumRoses, glad I could give you some input! Yes, do find ways to make it more comfortable for you. As you can see by Adrian's example there is a different way for each one of us. All the best!